# Microsoft Exchange Web Services - Detect Non-existent Email Address

Tags: email, email-verification

When I attempt to send an email through the exchange server with a badly formed email address, such as "firstname.lastname@gmail" (note ".com" is missing), I get an exception with the following message:

```
"At least one recipient isn't valid."
```

I can handle this.

But, when I send an email to a correctly formed, but non-existent email address, no exception is thrown. Is there a way to detect this?

I am using:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
```

Comment: Do you mean an email address that doesn’t exist on the same Exchange server, or just an address that happens not to exist globally? If the latter, how could the server know that without attempting to send to it?!

Comment: On the same server.